# Height of div with multiple toggles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write a piece of code that will add a scrollbar to a div if the expanded content is taller than the window height.

The html is roughly structured like this:

```
 <nav class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 no-padding">

     <div class="nav-container">

      <div class="tocify1">

<ul class="tocheader nav nav-list">
    <li class="multi flex-container active-top"><a class="open"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-rotate-90" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a href="link">Top Link</a></li>
    <ul id="" class="tocsubheader nav nav-list">
        <li class="active"><a href="link">Link 1</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="link">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the Css:

```
.nav-container{position: fixed;}
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
windowheight = $(window).height();

$('.open').click(function() {
          $(this).parent().next('.tocsubheader').slideToggle().promise().done(function(){

        sidenav = $('.tocify1').height();

        if (windowheight < sidenav){
          $('.tocify1').css({'height': windowheight, "overflow-y" : "scroll"});

        }
        else{
           $('.tocify1').css({'height':'100%', "overflow-y" : "hidden"});
        }
      });

  });
```

This works when one toggle is clicked, however when one toggle is open and another is clicked the sidenav height defaults to a seemingly arbitrary number less than the window height.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to use `outerHeight()`

Comment: Please add your html

Comment: does using `overflow-y: auto;` work?

Comment: Please pop up your html and it is quite possible with css alone using overflow-y:auto

Comment: Html added. It is coming from multiple sources so I only put a snippit.